# App Inventor WebViewer resize down

Tags: javascript, responsive, window-resize, app-inventor

I have an App with AppInventor 2, which basically holds a game from a website and a button in the lower part to go back to the main screen. The game uses Ajax to load some questions after a user clicks. Sometimes, the questions can be lengthy and the document height will increase, moving the button down, but after the question the game restores to the original size. (No page reloads are done in all the process, because everything is done with Ajax). The thing is, that the button does not go back up and remains at the bottom, each time a little lower and I don't know what to do.

All the game occurs in a second screen called Website.

The main screen (Screen1) has its sizing defined as Responsive and ScreenOrientation as Portrait. The AlignVertical property is set to 1 (Top)

[image]

Now, the Website screen also has AlignVertical to 1 (Top) and there is no Sizing option, so I am guessing it is inherited from Screen1.

[image]

Here is the Screen, I have tried everything, I resized the document in the HTML code with JavaScript but it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your setup currently is

VerticalArrangement2
- inside is a webviewer
 
- and another VerticalArrangement3 with a button inside

you have to rearrange your arrangements like this

VerticalArrangement2, set its height to fill parent
 - inside is a webviewer
VerticalArrangement3
-  inside is a button

i.e. both arrangements should be on the top level

and let me recommend you to NOT rename the default components like TinyDB, Webviewer, Web, Clock etc. else you might be confused a few weeks later after looking again at your project...